# computer software installing war file on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

How do I install a program in WAR format on my windows 7? I have downloaded a microfinance management software called MIFOS and after downloading it I realize that it's not in .exe format. I'm now stuck coz I'm unable to install it...please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Mifos is the platform / initiative, Mifos X is the software. It is a web-based app, meaning it runs on a server, rather than on your local computer.

From the [download page](http://mifos.org/take-action/get-mifos/):

> Download it on your own - Mifos X can be downloaded and **installed on-site on your own servers**.

As a WAR file is, according to Wikipedia,

> a file used to distribute a collection of JavaServer Pages, Java Servlets, (...) and other resources that together constitute a web application.

So, you need a web server able to run Java apps.

Comment: something like tomcat I guess...